# How do I find the 4th record in SQL/ SAS PROC SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

*Initially I tried including a sample SAS Table here but I can't get the script to line break where it should - Appreciate if you can let me know how to manually insert the line break when typing in the text editor, thanks*

**My question:**

For SAS PROC SQL - How can I return the 4th highest record (that is, after sorting - like a list of clietns/assets)? (i.e. I do not want 1st,2nd or 3rd, thus not using outobs=)

Similarly, what is the syntax for SQL (which might be different from SAS PROC SQL) - I believe it can utilize the LIMIT argument?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In data step you can use the automatic `_N_` variable.  For SQL, there is an undocumented function in SAS called `monotonic()`.  It gives you the record number.  Here are a couple ways to do what you need:

```
data blah;
letter = "ay "; number = 2;  output;
letter = "bea"; number = 3;  output;
letter = "see"; number = 42; output;
letter = "Dea"; number = 99; output;
letter = "Eee"; number = 1;  output;
run;


data new;
    set blah;
    theN = _N_; * if you want to save the record number;
    if theN = 4;
run;

proc sql;
    create table new2 as
        select blah.*, monotonic() as theN
            from blah
            having (theN = 4)
        ;
quit;
```

If the data is not sorted you can order it using an order by clause:

```
proc sql;
    create table ordered as
        select * from blah order by letter;
    create table new2 as
        select ordered.*, monotonic() as theN
            from ordered
            having (theN = 4);
    drop table work.ordered;
quit;
```

If the data is numeric you can also use proc rank.

```
data blah;
letter = "ay "; number = 2;  output;
letter = "bea"; number = 3;  output;
letter = "see"; number = 42; output;
letter = "Dea"; number = 99; output;
letter = "Eee"; number = 1;  output;
run;

proc rank data = blah out = new3 (where = (theRank = 4));
    var number;
    ranks theRank;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! And extra thanks for providing both the solution in data step and PROC SQL, very much appreciated.

Can I ask a follow up question though - now if I want to find the records with the 4th highest VALUE (taking into consideration records that may contain the value) what is the best way to do it?

For PROC SQL: I could use a INNER JOIN on distinct values, however in that case I can only do ascending (by default) as I cannot use ORDER BY DESC in the [INNER JOIN DISTINCT values statement] - am I correct?

Comment: @KeepWalking  Did you try PROC RANK?

Comment: I updated the answer to include the code to order the data and I added in proc rank (thank you @Tom).  If you are good hit the green checkmark.  If not, ask another question.